# Terminal command to start new google app engine project?

Tags: google-cloud-powershell

What is the command to create a new app engine project with skeleton files included? Since I can't use the launcher GUI on ubuntu, I've been successfully using dev_appserver.py through terminal.... but I've been copy and pasting files from hello world each time I make a new project folder. Is there a command line command to create a new project with the favicon and app.yaml etc.?

According to this documentation, the instructions are to make a new directory then copy the hello world files like I'm doing. https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/examples

But since the google app engine launcher GUI creates a new project with skeleton files included by a single button click, I wondered if there is a powershell command for this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command. Google Cloud Tools for PowerShell has not yet implemented support for App Engine. The list of supported features can be found [here](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/).

There is a `gcloud` command in beta that looks to do what you are asking for: [`gcloud beta app gen-config`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/gen-config).

Comment: Thank you. I voted your answer up but I'm too new for it to show.